# If a different factorial function would've been defined, what would the graph of this function look like?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, factorial, gamma-function

Let's define a new, different factorial function, such that $\frac{a}{b}!$ returns $\frac{a!}{b!}$. How would the graph of the function look like? For example, $\frac{1}{2}!$ does not return $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, instead $\frac{1!}{2!}$ (or just $\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: I tried plotting it (over the interval [0,1]) in Mathematica. It's kinda hard to see anything: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXZxB.png You can at least see the line of points $\left(\frac{n}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$ and loosely the parabola $\left(\frac{n}{n+2}, \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much Milo, though I really enjoyed reading other messages, my main goal was to see a graph, which you sent.

Answer (score 4):

There would be a number of dissatisfying properties that such a function would have:

- First, note that the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ would have to be in lowest terms. Otherwise, the function wouldn't be well-defined: would $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!$ equal $\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)!?$
- It would also be *highly* erratic. Note that $1!=1$, but $\left(\frac{400,001}{400,000}\right)!=400,001$. In any neighbourhood of $1$, we could find arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small outputs. This makes it very hard to graph the function.
- It would only be defined on the positive rationals.

Comment: I am aware of that, I just want to see a graph!

Comment: Ah, I see. I did think it would look very bad, but didn't think it would've been so dense it creates a block. Thank you!

Comment: @Tim: This isn't function you were asking about, but it might be informative to look at the graph of [$y=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sfubku8sxi). The graphing software finds it impossible to handle.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I remember reading that functions like these don't have a continuous derivative. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tim: I deleted my comment because I think it contains a mistake. I'm not actually sure how the graph would look like. I think as $x$ approaches $1$, it might actually be the case that $x!$ gets arbitrarily large or arbitrarily small. This is because if $\frac{a}{b}$ is approaching $1$, then both $a$ and $b$ would be getting larger. This means that if $a>b$, then $x!$ is very large, but if $a<b$, then $x!$ is very small. But don't quote me on this.

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure if the graph would look like a solid block of colour, because if $x$ is very close to (but not equal to) $1$, then I can't see how I could make $x! \approx 1$.

Comment: @Tim: Anyway, the derivative of $\sin(1/x)$ *is* continuous because it is equal to $-\frac{\cos(1/x)}{x^2}$. Because you can differentiate $-\frac{\cos(1/x)}{x^2}$, it is continuous. In fact, any function that you can differentiate is continuous. (The converse is not true—there are functions which are continuous but not differentiable, e.g. $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$ but continuous everywhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:x\mapsto f(x)$ be such a (real-valued) function, on a real domain to be determined which includes the positive integers. Since $f(x/y)=f(x)/f(y)$ for all $y\in\operatorname{dom}f$, we must have $0\notin\operatorname{dom}f$ and $0\notin\operatorname{range}f$. Setting $y=1$ gives $f(1)=1$. Also, for $y\neq0$, we have $f(x)=f(xy/y)=f(xy)/f(y)$. Hence
$$f(xy)=f(x)f(y).$$
Power functions such as $f:\Bbb R_{>0}\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x^a$, with constant $a\in\Bbb R$, fulfil this and the original condition. There are doubtless lots of pathological noncontinuous functions that do so as well

Comment: Some care appears to be needed in asserting $f(x/y) = f(x)/f(y)$. As Joe notes, OP's "definition" of $f(a/b)$ is not a definition without some additional hypothesis, e.g., $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. For instance, $2! = f(2) = f(4/2) \neq f(4)/f(2) = 4!/2!$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang : Sure, it's not a definition—just a property that Tim would like the function to have. He didn't even specify the domain. I interpreted “Let's define a new, different factorial function, such that [property P]. How would the graph of the function look like?” as “What sort of function would satisfy P?”. Your (reasonable) interpretation is that $f(n)=n!$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$, which is inconsistent with P (as you point out), and so P must be altered. Various interpretations are possible, since $f$ can be either factorial or new and different [from factorial], but not both.

Comment: My point was more than Tim's function does not satisfy $f(x/y) = f(x)/f(y)$. :)  That said, your answer does illuminate basic issues that need to be considered with this type of question.